# Construct 3-way contingency table in R

Tags: r, contingency

The 4 variables I have are: Breathless(B)= {y,n}, wheeze(W)= {y,n}, age={g1,g2,...,g5}, and count= {20 numeric counts}. I would like to construct a table as shown in the image, however the ftable function is unable to arrange the output properly into a table. How else can I construct it? Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

The output from ftable function:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to reshape your data using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
dcast(data, age + Breathless ~ wheeze, value.var = "count")
```

Comment: 'age+Breathless~ wheeze' sets 'age' and 'Breathless' to be on the row, 'wheeze' to be on the column?

Comment: Yes, think about it like what you have before `~` stays as rows and what is after `~` is kind of transposed to columns, and the values you want to fill in the reshaped table will be in argument  `value.var`. Check `?dcast` for more details

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = wheeze, values_from = count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is the names_from argument for the factor I wish to set in the column of the table, in this case 'wheeze'?